# Jquery mobile not a selectmenu object

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile and have a select menu in my html markup like this:

```
<select id="theid">
    <option>foo</option>
    ...
</select>
```

I actually would like to add some more options after an ajax call, so I do something like:

```
$('#theid').append(
    $('<option val="42">').text('bar')
)

$('#theid').selectmenu('refresh');
```

But sometimes I get an error that says that the object has no method 'selectmenu'. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
$('#theid').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-add-items-and-refresh-the-select-menu-in-jquery-mobile